# ¿Porque no itera el resultset despues de haber ejecutado la consulta?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, netbeans

estoy haciendo una consulta a mi base de datos usando inner join a varias tablas, pero cuando toca iterar no lo hace, la consulta la efectua correctamente, pero al llegar al resulSet.next no lo realiza.

Intente usar un try/catch para ver el problema y nisiquiera entra al ciclo, les dejo el codigo.

```
public void buscarParaModificar(Empleado empleado, FormModificar fm) {

        String sql ="SELECT empleados.cedula, "+
                   "empleados.nombre, "+
                   "empleados.apellido, "+
                   "empleados.fecha_nacimiento, "+
                   "empleados.sexo, "+
                   "empleados.profesion, "+
                   "empleados.telefono, "+
                   "empleados.celular, "+
                   "empleados.correo, "+
                   "empleados.direccion, "+
                   "estados.nombre_estado, "+
                   "tallas.franela, "+
                   "tallas.pantalon, "+
                   "tallas.zapato, "+
                   "datoMedico.Descripcion, "+
                   "nivel.nombre_nivel "+
        "FROM empleados INNER JOIN estados ON empleados.id_estado = estados.id "+
                       "INNER JOIN tallas ON empleados.id_talla = tallas.id "+
                       "INNER JOIN datoMedico ON empleados.id_datos_medicos = datoMedico.id "+
                       "INNER JOIN nivel ON empleados.id_nivel = nivel.id "+
        "WHERE empleados.cedula = '%"+empleado.getCedula()+"%' OR "+
               "empleados.nombre = '%"+empleado.getNombre()+"%' OR "+
               "empleados.apellido = '%"+empleado.getApellido()+"%' OR "+
               "empleados.correo = '%"+empleado.getCorreo()+"%'";

// datos get fueron obtenidos tras seleccionar una colummna de un JTable en un formulario

        try {

            st = getConnection().createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
// de aqui hacia abajo empieza el problema

            while(rs.next()){
                try{
                    fm.txtCedula.setText(rs.getString("empleados.cedula"));
                    fm.txtNombre.setText(rs.getString("empleados.nombre"));
                    fm.txtApellido.setText(rs.getString("empleados.apellido"));
                    fm.txtApellido.setText(rs.getString("empleados.fecha_nacimiento"));
                    fm.comSexo.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("empleados.sexo"));
                    fm.txtProfesion.setText(rs.getString("empleados.profesion"));
                    fm.txtTelefono.setText(rs.getString("empleados.telefono"));
                    fm.txtCelular.setText(rs.getString("empleados.celular"));
                    fm.txtCorreo.setText(rs.getString("empleados.correo"));
                    fm.txtDireccion.setText(rs.getString("empleados.direccion"));
                    fm.comEstado.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("estados.nombre_estado"));
                    fm.comFranela.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("tallas.franela"));
                    fm.comPantalon.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("tallas.pantalon"));
                    fm.comZapato.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("tallas.zapato"));
                    fm.txtDatosMedicos.setText(rs.getString("datoMedico.Descripcion"));
                    fm.comNivel.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("nivel.nombre_nivel"));

                }catch(SQLException el){
                    System.out.println("No itera por: \n"+el);
                }
                System.out.println("Ejecucion correcta: "+sql);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error en EmpleadoDAO.busquedaDatos:\n"+e);
        }
    }
```

Lo que necesito es que los datos SELECT sean mostrados en sus respectivas cajas (JTextField y JComboBox) de otro formulario para proceder con el metodo de modificar los datos

Comment: Lo más habitual es que la consulta no devuelva ningún resultado. ¿Has intentado ejecutarla en la consola SQL?

Comment: si, manda un error diciendo: El conjunto de resultados no tiene fila actual. 

Pero a que se refiere? cuando hago la consulta en sql server me muestra los datos que deberia traerse.

Comment: Es error se dió cuando cambié el while(rs.next()) por un do{}while(rs.next()) 

Tambien comprobe que recibiera los datos que necesita para hacer la consulta, esos son los que se encuentran declarados en String sql, done esta el WHERE con la clase modelo de empleado y sus respectivos getter, esta parte tambien es correcta.

Comment: Tu error no tiene nada que ver con tu codigo. Tu error es tu sql que no esta funcionando. Por favor, cambiemos la pregunta hasta que tu query devuelva lo que vos queres. Para eso necesitamos ver tu query, las tablas involucradas, los datos que queres que devuelva y los que devuelve. Como recomendacion, empeza metiendo de a uno los campos que queres en tu consulta.

Comment: No estoy seguro que tu consulta funcione bien, en ella usas comodines para cláusulas `LIKE` en criterios de igualdad, por ejemplo aquí, y en los otros: `empleados.cedula = '%"+empleado.getCedula()+"%'` ...  el comodín `%` se usa con `LIKE`
. Y, para verificar si hay datos o no puedes hacer algo así: `if (!rs.isBeforeFirst() ) {  //mostrar mensaje de que no encontró datos } else { while(rs.next()){ //tu código que recupera los datos } }` La eventualidad de que **no encontró datos** no aparece contemplada en un tu código, si no encuentra datos se queda mudo, eso no se controla en un `catch`